# @XmlElement with multiple names

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have a situation here, trying to act as a gateway between two APIs. What I need to do, is:

1. make a request to an APIa;
2. parse (marshal) the XML response into an java object;
3. make little changes to it;
4. and then give a response in XML (unmarshal) to the other end (APIb).

The thing is that I use the same object to parse the API response and to send the response to the other end.

```
public class ResponseAPI{

@XmlElement(name="ResponseCode") //I receive <ResponseCode> but I need to send <ResultCode>
private String responseCode;

//getter and setter
}
```

as the comment says: I receive  but I need to send

Is there a way to get this done without having to create another extra class which carries ResultCode?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:**

The [answer given by Ilya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24569223/383861) works but isn't guaranteed to work across all implementations of JAXB or even across versions of a single JAXB implementation.  The `@XmlElements` annotation is useful when the decision of which element to marshal depends on the type of the value (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html).  In your use case both the `ResponseCode` and `ResultCode` elements correspond to type `String`, unmarshalling will always work fine, but the choice of which element to output is arbitrary.  Some JAXB Impls may have last specified wins, but others could easily have first wins.

---

You could do the following by leveraging `@XmlElementRef`.

### Java Model

**ResponseAPI**

We will change the `responseCode` property from type `String` to `JAXBElement<String>`.  The `JAXBElement` allows us to store the element name as well as the value.

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ResponseAPI{

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "ResponseCode"),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "ResultCode")
    })
    private JAXBElement<String> responseCode;

    public JAXBElement<String> getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public void setResponseCode(JAXBElement<String> responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

}
```

**ObjectFactory**

The `@XmlElementRef` annotations we used on the `ResponseAPI` class correspond to `@XmlElementDecl` annotations on a class annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.  Traditionally this class is called `ObjectFactory` but you can call it anything you want.

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name="ResponseCode")
    public JAXBElement<String> createResponseCode(String string) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("ResponseCode"), String.class, string);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name="ResultCode")
    public JAXBElement<String> createResultCode(String string) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("ResultCode"), String.class, string);
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**input.xml**

```
<responseAPI>
    <ResponseCode>ABC</ResponseCode>
</responseAPI>
```

**Demo**

When creating the `JAXBContext` we need to ensure that we include the class that contains the `@XmlElementDecl` annotations.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ResponseAPI.class, ObjectFactory.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("Scratch/src2/forum24554789/input.xml");
        ResponseAPI responseAPI = (ResponseAPI) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        String responseCode = responseAPI.getResponseCode().getValue();
        JAXBElement<String> resultCodeJAXBElement = objectFactory.createResultCode(responseCode);
        responseAPI.setResponseCode(resultCodeJAXBElement);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(responseAPI, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<responseAPI>
    <ResultCode>ABC</ResultCode>
</responseAPI>
```

Comment: This is awesome! thank you very much for this well-explained info, it was totally unknown to me. I'll come back here and give my proof of concept when I'll have it implemented. I need to go further on researching some other stuff before get this done. Thanks again!

Comment: Really nice, but what in case I don't want to implement ObjectFactory. Shouldn't be XmlElementRef annotation enough to unmarshal my object? I don't want to marshal it.

Comment: Hi Blaise,

I was wondering if the XmlAdapter could be enhanced somehow to deal with marshaling dynamic element names (i.e. given at runtime). For example, one idea would be to enhancement XmlAdapter so that during unmarshaling, it gets passed in not just the unmarshaled value but also the name of the element or attribute being unmarshaled. And during marshaling we return both the element name as well as the value.

Comment: Also it might be useful to allow the user to specify a factory method for creating the XmlAdapter instance (so that we can introduce some application specific state in the instance to help in deciding how to marshal.unmarshal). 

I dont know how the XmlAdapter is instantiated when an XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation is processed but I am assuming that the instance is cached and re-used for every subsequent invocation (since its stateless). But the factory method I am suggesting can also do the same (since the method can return a singleton if the state it contains is independent of each record).

Answer (score 8):

You can try next solution using [@XmlElements](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html) annotaion

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ResponseAPI 
{
   @XmlElements(
      {
         @XmlElement(name = "ResponseCode"),
         @XmlElement(name = "ResultCode")
      })
   private String responseCode;
   // ...
}
```

In this case both `ResponseCode` and `ResultCode` will be used during unmarshalling (xml -> object) and only `ResultCode` during marshalling (object -> xml).

So you can unmarshall XML like

```
<responseAPI>
    <ResponseCode>404</ResponseCode>
</responseAPI>
```

After marshalling object will looks like

```
<responseAPI>
    <ResultCode>404</ResultCode>
</responseAPI>
```

Comment: This answer can produce the correct output, but isn't guaranteed to work.  I've posted an answer with some additional explanation.