# What is the alternative to using @XmlElements?

Tags: xml, spring, rest, web-services, jaxb

For example let's say you have an interface Animal
And then you have 100 implementations like :
LION
CAT
DOG
CHEETAH
ELEPHANT
And many more

And when sending this in the response, you will have to specify all the Actual implementations like

`@XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(type=MutableLion.class)
        @XmlElement(type=MutableCat.class)
        and many more
})`

Is there a better way to do this, instead of specifying 100 implementations as annotations?

Comment: Can you check this if it helps, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42304008/7977273

Comment: But this requires another Wrapper like DogWrapper on top of every implementations. That is probably not a good idea. Also is there a way I can do without changing anything in the implementations?