# Jaxb - Two-way renaming

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've a problem regarding jaxb. To explain the context :

My service calls an external webservice. I receive a xml response with some ugly property names.

I actually use `@XmlElement(name="___")` to rename the properties of my pojo.

For example :

```
@XmlElement(name = "uglyName")
    private String beautyName;
```

It works correctly but then I need to use jaxb to marshall it in the other way and the ugly name is sent to the response (from source xml, present into the anotation).

So what I want :

```
Source xml : Name = 'class' 
My class : Name = 'fundClass' 
Into my xml return : Name = 'fundClass'.
```

I hope I was clear ...

Thanks,

Comment: You want to parse the XML with `<uglyName>` into object using JAXB, then write that back out to XML with `<beautyName>`?  If you're just transforming the data, why go through the overhead of JAXB? Why not just *transform* the XML from `<uglyName>` to `<beautyName>` using XSLT?

Comment: I've never did that. Is this easy to implement ? If I understand you, this xslt will just rename my fields to the correct name before doing the unmarshalling ? Seems a good idea! Thanks

Comment: Similar question was asked in this topic: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554789/xmlelement-with-multiple-names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554789/xmlelement-with-multiple-names)

Comment: It works with the solution found on the topic. Thanks!